# Calculate IRR for uneven cashflow

Tags: python, numpy

I have a DataFrame of uneven cashflow, and I need to generate a backward-looking IRR.I have tried with numpy.irr method but that will work if payment is `np.irr(cashflows,rate)`

but the problem is cashflow is unpredictable and we have to change the IRR on the basis of emi paid .

for example

month opening_balance emi closing_balance

1. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
2. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
3. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
4. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
5. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
6. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
7. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
8. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```
9. ```
    xx            xy     yz
   ```

so let suppose loan has pre_paid in 4th month (xy+ 500)
and tenure is same , so how can i adjust remaining amount and calculate irr where NPV should be 0

Comment: Can you show an example with the sort of cash flows you'd expect.  `cashflows` in np.irr is an array. So the flows can be different for each period.  np.irr has been moved to numpy-financials from numpy version 1.20.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using a loop to iterate over a range of potential IRR values, and then use a function to calculate the PV of the cashflow at each IRR value. You can then compare the PV to the total cash outflow, and stop the loop when the present value is equal to or greater than the total cash outflow. The IRR value at which this occurs will be the backward-looking IRR.

```
def backward_irr(cashflow, rate):
    # get total CF
    total_outflow = sum([x for x in cashflow if x < 0])

    for irr in np.arange(0, 1, 0.01):
        present_value = sum([x / (1 + irr) ** t for t, x in enumerate(cashflow)])

        if present_value >= total_outflow:
            return irr

#CF example
cashflow = [-100, 20, 40, 60, 80]
rate = backward_irr(cashflow, 0.1)
print(rate)
```

try it an report result

Comment: No its not working.